# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Philosophy's [third moderator election](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Geoffrey Thomas]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5990621789552640/0).

Comment: Congrats. Don't be a stranger in Meta!

Comment: @curiousdannii. Thank you. Point taken : I will not neglect Meta. I have not taken proper advantage of it yet. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: Congratulations @GeoffreyThomas. (I hope I am not too late)

Comment: @user 170039. Never too late - and much appreciated. Your time will come. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @ Frank Hubeny. I hoped you would stand. It was only because it looked as if you hadn't applied that I put myself forward. By the time I had posted my statement, your name was there. Straight out : you would make an excellent moderator. In fact you are doing a large part of a moderator's job already. I will be very disappointed if you don't get the next opening. As it was, the voting was  v. close between us. All the best - Geoffrey.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas Thank you and I am glad you ran. Actually, I was expecting you to run. I had no intention of running in this, but I became worried when I didn't see anyone I recognized nominate themselves. It looks like we both had similar concerns. Best wishes. You will do a good job. And congratulations!

Comment: So happy you're gonna be an official mod from now on Geoffrey. Congratulations man, you have a whole lot to contribute to this community, and I do have high expectations from you!